# SVG - Clip-path only works when defined within same <svg> tags

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG star that I define *externally*, and then include within the DOM using `use`:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="Star" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
      <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon star" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
  <title>Add Favorite</title>
  <use xlink:href="#Star"></use>
</svg>
```

In this case, it is simply defined at the top of the body, but in practice will be an external file.

What I'd like to do is make the star appear to be filling in, from the outside. To do this, I add a `stroke-width` transition, and clip the SVG with the same path:

```
*HTML*

<svg class="icon star" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
      <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <title>Add Favorite</title>
  <use xlink:href="#Star" clip-path="url(#clip)"></use>
</svg>


*CSS*

.icon {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.star {
  fill: #0F0;
  stroke: #F00;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  transition: stroke-width 200ms linear;
}
.star:hover {
  stroke-width: 50%;
}
```

And it works a treat! Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Birrel/uq37cxep/)

*BUT*, when I try to move the `clipPath` definition up to the top...

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
      <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <defs>
    <symbol id="Star" viewBox="0 0 256 244" clip-path="url(#clip)">
      <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon star" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
  <title>Add Favorite</title>
  <use xlink:href="#Star"></use>
</svg>
```

... it doesn't work anymore. Here is a [not working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Birrel/uq37cxep/1/).

There is no change if I include the `clip-path="url(#clip)"` within the `use` below. Same result. Likewise, for adding it within the CSS:

```
.star {
  ...
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

So, what gives? How are the two different from one another? If I ***MUST*** use the first method, then so be it. But ideally, I'd like to keep the DOM as clean as possible, and have all the SVG definitions separate - or at least together at the top.

Comment: **OK that seemed to do the trick! But then what do I do about the giant gaping hole left by the un-styled SVG definition?**

Comment: Yep, you beat me to the punch. I *just* ran it and was coming back to comment it. Winner-winner. Thnx, Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: none is best avoided where SVG content is concerned. It turns off CSS and things like clip-path are CSS mapped attributes so they no longer work.

Use width="0" and height="0" instead (or set the outer SVG width and height via CSS if you want).

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Longson suggested the `display: none` is best avoided.

Replacing it with `width: 0; height: 0;` fixed the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/uq37cxep/12/